# Image byte stream is different when file is read in different ways

Tags: java, spring, maven, resources, png

Under my Spring  4.3/Maven 3.3 project I have an image file, a PNG file, at:
src/main/resources/images/account.png

I have a util java application file that reads in an image, and it writes it to the database field.   The code is as follows:

```
private static String _accountFilename = "src/main/resources/images/account.png";

private byte[] getByteArrayFromFile(String filename)
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    File file = new File(filename);

    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    try
    {
        // convert file into array of bytes
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print((char) bFile[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bFile;
}

public String getImageData(byte[] imageByteArray)
{
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

    String base64 = encoder.encodeToString(imageByteArray);
    base64 = "data:image/png;base64," + base64;
    return base64;
}
```

The String that comes back from "getImageData" works great.  I can put that String in the MySQL database, in a table, and the field is defined as TEXT.
I can pull that base64 encoded data back, and display the image.

Now, If I am calling this code from a Spring Service instead of an application, then the image "src/main/resources/images/account.png" is not found.

After researching on the Net for some time, there are many, many examples of getting a file from "resources" and many of these did not work for me.  Since I am in Spring, I tried a few things and finally this worked:

```
@Value(value = "classpath:images/account.png")
private Resource defaultAccountImage;

private byte[] getByteArrayFromFile(Resource image)
{
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    byte[] bFile = null;

    try
    {
        bFile = new byte[(int) image.contentLength()];

        // convert file into array of bytes
        inputStream = image.getInputStream();
        inputStream.read(bFile);
        inputStream.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print((char) bFile[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bFile;
}

private String getImageData(byte[] imageByteArray)
{
    Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    String base64 = encoder.encodeToString(imageByteArray);
    base64 = "data:image/png;base64," + base64;
    return base64;
}

public String getDefaultAccountImage()
{
    byte[] accountImage = getByteArrayFromFile(defaultAccountImage);
    String fileString = getImageData(accountImage);
    return fileString;
}
```

When I look at the String/Image data between the first way with the standalone java app, and the second way with the @Value and inputstream, there is a definite different in the string data.

part of the string data is similar, but then it drastically changes, and they don't match.   As a result the text data for the image from the second method doesn't display as an image.

So, I was hoping I could get this image text data, and it would be the same, but it is not.   If I can use my web-service, which calls the business service which calls this ImageUtil code where I use the @Value to get the image resource and it saves the text string correctly, that would be great.

If you have any advice, I would very much appreciate it.     Thanks!

UPDATE 1:
This is a multi-maven project:

```
parent-project
      entity
      dao
      service
      ws
```

When I run my test code within the Service layer, the suggested solution works great!   The images are found and the byte string gets loaded as it should be.   And then I compiled the code into a jar.

The entity.jar gets created first.
The dao.jar gets created and pulls in the entity.jar.
The service.jar gets created and pulls in the dao.jar.  This layer also has the /resources/images/account.png file.   But this image is now in the jar.
The ws.WAR file pulls in the service.jar file ...
so the code in the answer does not find the image in the resources.
When I run the tests from the ws layer, I get a FileNotFoundException.

So ... now I am researching on how to get an image from jar ...

Does this change how I should be getting my image byte array?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file from the Resource, and proceed like the first example which works. Seems redundant, but if you can get the file, then you can test a number of things:

1. Write the file to disk and check the content
2. Write the file to disk and compare the sizes, etc.

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
   import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

   @Value(value = "classpath:images/account.png")
   private Resource defaultAccountImage;

   private byte[] getByteArrayFromFile(Resource image) {

       FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

       byte[] bFile = null;


       try {
           File file = image.getFile();
           bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

           // convert file into array of bytes
           fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
           fileInputStream.read(bFile);
           fileInputStream.close();

           for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
               System.out.print((char) bFile[i]);
           }

           System.out.println("Done");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return bFile;
   }
   ```

Comment: This doesn't quite work.   This is a multi-maven project.  The web-services endpoint is in a maven module called "app-ws".  This module pulls in a jar file "app-service.jar" which is another maven module.  When I run the test in the "service" code, it works great and finds the file.   Then it gets compiled into a jar.   So, when the code runs from "ws" then the images is not in the local resources directory, that image is in the service jar within the resources directory of that jar.   So, how do I get the image from the resources within the jar?